# nginx sites in subfolders

Tags: php, nginx

I have some trouble getting my nginx setup work the way I want. I have a site example.localhost that is located at /vagrant/frontend/www. My configuration for this, which is working, looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.localhost;

    root /vagrant/frontend/www;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ .*\.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

But then I want to add an admin site, located at /vagrant/backend/www, to the address example.localhost/admin. This is when things go wrong, and I get a 404 not found with the setup below, based on [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/218818/nginx-projects-in-subfolders):

```
location /admin {
    root /vagrant/backend/www;
}  

location ~ /admin/.+\.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

The error log looks like this:

```
2014/04/23 12:30:10 [error] 15459#0: *1 "/vagrant/backend/www/admin/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.56.1, server: example.localhost, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.localhost"
```

I see why I get a 404, but how do I get this right? Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I have changed my admin location to this:

```
location /admin {
    alias /vagrant/backend/www/;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

I have also removed this block:

```
location ~ /admin/.+\.php$ {...}
```

Now a call to example.localhost/admin gets processed correct, but if I change it to eg example.localhost/admin/site/index, the request is processed by the frontend. It looks like the /admin location doesn't match... Any thoughts?

Comment: If "/vagrant/backend/www/admin/index.php" is not found, where is actual file is?

Comment: The file is here: /vagrant/backend/www/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.localhost;

    root /vagrant/frontend/www;
    index index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include fastcgi.conf;
            }
    }

    location /admin {
            return 301 /admin/;
    }

    location /admin/ {
            alias /vagrant/backend/www/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include fastcgi.conf;
            }
    }

    location @handler {
            rewrite / /admin/index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`location` blocks are completely independent. Your request ends up in last `location` block and never see `root` directive from first one. Put `root` directive to second block.

```
location ~ /admin/.+\.php$ {
    root /vagrant/backend/www;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your proposal, but now I got routed to the frontend, eventually ending up with an exception. It looks to me like the location block doesn't match, and therefore the "default" root is used...

Comment: Place this block before location block for other php files. For regexp locatin blocks nginx uses first that match

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunatelly it didn't do any difference. From what I have read, the position of the location blocks doesn't matter, as the regex that gives the most precise hit is chosen.

Comment: No. Prefix locations do not depend on order, but regex locations do.